# Split the string from character and that character I don't want remove

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I want to split string in JS. I already know function `str.split();` but I want something different. like: 
i have string `var str = "Hello word"` . i have to split these string from character `o` than string converted in array like : `array = ['hell', 'o' , ' w', 'o','rd']`

```
var str = "Hello word"
var ary = str.split("o");
//     output : ary = ['hell', ' w' ,'rd'];
//     I want : ary = ['hell', 'o' , ' w', 'o','rd'];
```

please anyone help to how can I get output like these.

Comment: Use indexOf and substring. You may start spliting with spaces.

Comment: If `o` is just an example, and you want to split just on some digit from a specific range, then a regex solution is viable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var str = "Hello word"
var ary = str.split(/(o)/));
//ary = ['hell', 'o' , ' w', 'o','rd'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually want `match`, not `split`.

```js
str = "Hello word"
ary = str.match(/o|[^o]+/g)
document.write(ary)
```

`split(/(o)/)` also works, but do note:

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array. **However, not all browsers support this capability.** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Capturing_parentheses)